# Google Cloud storage invalid credentials

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have two questions.

Question 1)

```
$storage = new StorageClient(['projectId'=>"thisisreal"]);

    $bucket = $storage->bucket('bucketnameunique');

    // Upload a file to the bucket.
    $bucket->upload(
        fopen('../test.txt', 'r')
    );
```

This is my code. I'm 100% sure projectId is correct and bucketname is correct, but still this code gives me invalid credentials errors. What else could I try?

Question 2) after I solve the above problem, I want to store pictures documents some kind of files. So basically one type of user will have only pictures, other type of users will have only documents and so on. What should I do?

- Option 1: should I have only one bucket and in that bucket, I will create folders like (user_type_1_folder will have only pictures, user_type_2_folder will have only documents).
- Option 2: should I have different bucket for pictures, documents and files? what is a better way? is it about performance?

Comment: Did you make ANY ATTEMPT to login to google before trying to fiddle with a secure area? If not that would explain why Google is complaining

Comment: what do you mean login? I have google developer console. I'm in. that's where I copied my projectId.

Comment: So where is the PHP code running?

Comment: It's located on my server.

Comment: So that code is NOT logged in, therefore the credentials error

Comment: This example code will show you how to user "Service Account" credentials in PHP. https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/blob/master/AUTHENTICATION.md